# Configuring Qt Command Prompt

Tags: c++, qt, batch-file, static-libraries

I'd like to run my Qt application as a standalone executable. I know that I have to configure Qt to build static applications to do this and have added the line of code for this to my .pro file but I cannot get the Qt command prompt to work in order to complete the configuration.

The command prompt mentions I need to call vcvarsall.bat to complete environment setup. Could I get some pointers on how to get this batch file to run and what other steps I need to complete to build static applications. I'm using version 5.3 and the compiler is MSVC 2012.

Edit: I've found the vcvarsall.bat file and tried running it by dragging and dropping it into the cmd window but it was not recognised.

Comment: I suppose that with "static application" you mean that you want your  application linked with statically linked libraries. If that is the case, then you first need to have Qt fully compiled to produce static versions of the libraries which is not a default option. Also I would like to remember that if you are using a free version of Qt to produce an LGPL or GPL app the Qt license does not allow static linking .

Comment: yes, such that I can run it as a single executable on another system. I'm trying to change the qt configuration using the qt command prompt, do you have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup your environment using `vcvarsall.bat` you need to run it like

```
%COMSPEC% /k "C:\path\to\vcvarsall.bat"
```

Few simple steps to build static Qt would be:

```
cd C:\path\to\Qt
configure.exe -static -release
nmake
```

Explaining how to build static Qt applications is beyond this SO question. Please proceed to http://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows.

Comment: I've used that link before. I did what was described but the command prompt does not recognize any of the commands (configure, static, release) even after calling vcvarsall.bat my environment does not get setup.

Comment: Do you find `configure.exe` in `C:\path\to\Qt`?

Comment: There is no executable in the path. Isn't configure just a command for the prompt that allows me begin editing the way Qt is setup?

Comment: `configure.exe` is a binary executable that resides in the archive with Qt sources. It's not a system command. Where did you download the sources from? Did you understand that `C:\path\to\Qt` is the directory where you extracted the archive with Qt sources.

Comment: I've been searching, there is no executable. Where were you able to find it on your system? I got the sources from the Qt site, I didn't need to extract them though

Comment: Where did you download the sources from? How do you extract them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71787/discussion-between-duanne-and-svlasov).